# Probability of nested groups

Tags: probability

I've got a simple question here.

Say I have three groups (A, B, C). Group A consists of the numbers 1-9. Group B consists of 1-3. Group C has 5 numbers, randomly selected from A without replacement.  How would I determine the probability of Group C containing B?

If clarification is needed, do let me know. I'll respond as soon as I check back. In addition, please do be patient with me. Probability was one of the hardest parts of my high school math career; I've always had a lot of trouble wrapping my head around this kind of thing. Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Don't worry at all about an explanation. I'm only looking for a formula.

Comment: Group C *must* contain $1-3$ , so basically you just need to select any two numbers from $4-9$ of group A, which is small enough that you can count it out if you don't know the combination formula $^6C_2$

Comment: @trueblueanil 6C2 comes out to 15 on my calculator. Just to confirm 100%, it would be a 1/15 chance?

Comment: No, I have clarified in a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Group C to contain Group B, it *must* have $1-3$ + two more numbers from $4=9$

I had just given a shortcut for the favorable ways, the full formula for the desired *probability* for selection without replacement would be

$ \Large\frac{\binom33\binom62}{\binom95} = \frac{15}{126}$

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your response and patience, it's very much appreciated! You have a good one.

Comment: Glad to have been of help ! $\;\;$ :)